# Indexing using noquote() in R

Tags: r, indexing

If we have the following specified:

```
testmatrix <- matrix(seq(1:12), nrow=3, ncol=4)
colnames(testmatrix) <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")

index1 <- c("one", "two")
index2 <- c("two", "three")
index3 <- c("three", "four")
```

Why does this work:

```
apply(testmatrix[,index1], 1, sum)
```

But this does not?

```
apply(testmatrix[,(noquote(paste0("index", 1)))], 1, sum)
```

The reason I ask is because I need to apply the sum function to the columns specified within the "index" variables and add it to the matrix for each of these variables. I had thought to do it as follows, but it does not work.

```
nindex <- 3

for (i in 1:nindex) {
    testmatrix <- cbind(testmatrix, apply(testmatrix[,(noquote(paste0("index", i)))], 1, sum))
}
```

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simpler option (among many, I'm sure):

```
ind <- list(index1 = index1,
            index2 = index2,
            index3 = index3)

for (i in seq_along(ind)) {
  testmatrix <- cbind(testmatrix, apply(testmatrix[,ind[[i]]], 1, sum))
}
```

Whatever you do, just abandon `noquote`, it doesn't have anything to do with what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Follow-up question: How would you make the list of indices if the number of index variables is variable? For example, one user has two (index1, index2) and another has four (index1, index2, index3, index4)? The format of the variable names stays the same ("index" + integer).

Comment: @EvadeSchipper You'd need to provide more context on what you mean by "user" and the context under which this script is running. Somehow the variables `index1`, `index2`, etc are being created but I have no idea how.

Comment: The "user" would be a data-analyst, using my code. I would like to be able to have them specify only the number of `index` variables and their content, like this: `nindex <- 3`, `index1 <- c("one", "two")`, `index2 <-` etc. And then do the rest for them, because the analysts are not acquainted with R at all. So preferably, I would create the list (as you suggested above) based on this information that they specified. Does this make sense?

Comment: @EvadeSchipper I don't quite understand why having them type that is any more complicated than having them type `ind <- list(index1 = ...,index2 = ...)` etc.

Comment: At this point, they have to, and it's not a very big deal. Theoretically though, I would still like to know how I can do it, if it is possible to do it. As a learning experience. I'm rather new to programming. If it is not possible, then having them type the extra line themselves is perfectly fine.

Comment: @EvadeSchipper Well, I was sort of trying to avoid telling you about `mget`, mainly because it's best not to develop habits that rely on it (and related functions that you will find in the process) when you're beginning. Perhaps a better direction to go in would be to explicitly prompt for user input via `readline`.